# Joomla 1.0 - need to add drop down menu into existing template

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, joomla, menubar

What is the best and easiest way to add a drop down menu to an existing template in Joomla 1.0 (can't upgrade it)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module SwFreeMenu works with 1.0 afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what sort of options do you with to provide in that menu. If it's just some static stuff, like `Select language: (options) English, German, Spanish`, you might get away with adding that directly to the template by editing the template's HTML markup in the right place.

However, if you intend to do something more dynamic, than template is not the place to hack. You may want to create a "module" and ten add it to your list of site modules, to a desired position defined by the template. Then you can set which pages is this module going to appear on. I believe you can duplicate a simple module like the search box, and then change the module's code. I haven't done it before but I bet it's pretty simple.